# How to update, instead of flush and re-write, iptables rules

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

Currently I'm updating my `iptables` rules using a bash script, where I call the command:

```
iptables -F
```

then I apply the rules.

The problem being that I need to update the rules to gain access to port 80, then I drop everything, in a cron job every 10 minutes. So every 10 minutes I call `iptables -F` to delete old rules and open all ports (the thing I don't want).

I want to not have to flush the rules every 10 minutes, just edit or update the existing rules.

Comment: do firewall rules change so often ? `iptables` can use `-A` (append) `-I` (insert) or `-D`(delete) flags. can't you diff old and new rules and use -D/(-A or -I) ?

Comment: Then there's iptables-save, iptables-restore and more importantly iptables-apply (available in CentOS8+). The whole ruleset could be versioned with git. Also iptables -F can kill a working connection when the policy was set to DROP. So more commands should be run in the crontab with the current scheme.

Comment: Archemar here is the situation, my isp changes my router ip often I need to change iptables rule, I use a dyn domain to add a record for the ip I'm currently provided with by the internet provider. the iptable rule gives access to the A record of my domain name. I need to apply the rule change everytime my ip changes

Comment: I would also recommend using append/insert/delete as needed, but for the sake of keeping the current state, it's actually necessary to have the full state saved to continue at the next restart for example.  You can create a full dump of the iptables rules with ìptables-save >/etc/myrules/iptables.save`for example, ideally after any change, and then `iptables-restore /etc/myrules/iptables.save` when needed, which still may trigger delays or outages, however.  `nftables`, if your distro supports it, may be more suitable, it's able to replace full tables in an *atomic* manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are specific rules that need to be updated regularly, I would put them in a separate chain, calling that chain from `INPUT` in an appropriate slot

```
iptables -N mychain                # Create new chain "mychain"
iptables -A INPUT mychain          # Insert it into INPUT
iptables -A INPUT …other rules…    # Append other rules as before
```

Now you can flush and add the frequently changing rules in `mychain` without affecting the rules in `INPUT`:

```
iptables -F mychain
iptables -A mychain …rule…
iptables -A mychain …rule…
…
```

If you really want to have these added as a single entity as if it were in a transaction, you could create the chain, add your rules to that chain, and then insert that chain into `INPUT`, removing the previous instance immediately afterwards. You would probably want dynamic chain names for this. For example,

```
chain="mychain_$(date +%s)"    # One second granularity
iptables -N "$chain"           # Create the chain
iptables -A "$chain" …rule…    # and its rules
iptables -A "$chain" …rule…
iptables -A "$chain" …rule…
…
```

then

```
old=$(iptables -L INPUT | awk '$1 ~ /^mychain_[0-9]+$/ {print $1; exit}')
iptables -I INPUT 1 -j "$chain"    # Add new chain in correct position
if [ -n "$old" ]
then
    iptables -D INPUT -j "$old"    # Remove old chain
    iptables -X "$old"             # Delete it
fi
```

On the other hand, if your requirement is to block or permit large numbers of IP addresses you would be better looking at an [IP set](https://ipset.netfilter.org/).

Comment: This is more of a complete answer than mine so I'll mark it as the proper answer

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Rules is possible.

Here is an example:

First you can create a rule at the top (first) position with this command :

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Rules can be specified to replace existing Rules in the chain.

The first Rule given on position 1 was allowing connections to the http port (port 80) from anywhere.

The following iptables command replaces the Rule, restricting connections to the standard http port (port 80) only from the network address range 192.168.0.0/24:

```
iptables -R INPUT 1 -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

so Instead of deleting all the rules, you just need to know the position of the rules you need to replace.

Here's the full how to course [source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules)